# How can i convert an input number say 032817103305 into a format 03/28/17 10 33 05 using perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to convert a 12 digit number e.g. 032817103305 into a format 03/28/17 10 33 05 using Perl?

Comment: What's the relationship between `103305` and `11 10 08`?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: my bad !!! key board issue.

Comment: i am basically getting a number e.g. 032817103305  and i would like to convert this number into the format 03/28/17 10 33 05 . this is basically means current date and followed by hh mm ss

Answer (score 2):

```
$str =~ s{^(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)}{$1/$2/$3 $4 $5 $6};
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex substitution is better for just reformatting the numbers, but [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) can also come in handy if you want to other things with the individual fields (eg, insert into a database etc):

```
my $record = '032817103305';
my ($month, $day, $year, $hr, $min, $sec) = unpack 'A2' x 6, $record;
```